# How to save a MongoDB Query and run It afterwards?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am mounting a MongoDB Query in **Application A**. For example:

```
const query = { country: new ObjectId(""), age: { $gte: 25 } }
// save contents of 'query'
```

... And I want to save It in de DB and make the **Application B** run It:

```
// const query = read object from the database
db.collection('foo').find(query).toArray()...
```

I want to save It in mongo now and retrieve It in a later period to run. But MongoDB doesn't allow me to save a document with `$gte` value. I've already tried to `JSON.stringify(query)`, save the result String in the DB (Ok!) and then parse It on the other side.

Then, faced the problem where the `ObjectId` gets stringified like this:

```
{
    "class" : "org.bson.types.ObjectId",
    "counter" : 9053980.0,
    "date" : "2015-04-01T19:24:39Z",
    "machineIdentifier" : 14987412.0,
    "processIdentifier" : 29601.0,
    "time" : 1427916279000.0,
    "timeSecond" : 1427916279.0,
    "timestamp" : 1427916279.0
}
```

The parsed JSON is not a valid ObjectId.  It's just a JS Object.

**How can I save the MongoDB Query and parse It to an object that mongo will accept again?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use [MongoDB Extended JSON module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extended-json)

We shouldn't stringify and parse MongoDB Objects as if they are pure Javascript Objects.

To parse MongoDB Objects we have to use Mongodb-Extended-JSON module. Since there are some types that can not be parsed to pure JSON, Mongo translates Its objects to a special JSON (Extended JSON).

### Solution

**On Application A**:

```
const EJSON = require('mongodb-extended-json')
const query = { country: new ObjectId(""), age: { $gte: 25 } }
const strQuery = EJSON.stringify(query)
// { "country": { "$oid": "5422c2e6e4b02fd68a01225c" }, "age": { "$gte": 25 } }
```

**On Application B**:

```
const EJSON = require('mongodb-extended-json')
const query = EJSON.parse(strQuery)
const query = EJSON.stringify(query)
// query is now a MongoDB Object that can be used on db.collection('foo').find(query)
```

Comment: Thanks - just a note however - this module has been moved to  `mongodb-extjson` - here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extjson

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the `ObjectId` to string first with `.toString()`, and then when deserializing convert the string back to a proper `ObjectId`:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

let query = {
  country: new ObjectId('590a0953ca81dd490ee8dba3'),
  age: {
    $gte: 25
  }
};

query.country = query.country.toString();
const serialized = JSON.stringify(query);

console.log(serialized);

let deserialized = JSON.parse(serialized);
deserialized.country = new ObjectId(deserialized.country);

console.log(deserialized);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @vesse ! I posted this question because I struggled with this problem for days. Then, I found the solution. Your solution works around the problem with simple queries, with an ObjectId, but we would have to handle every ObjectId in a more complex query, ex.: `{ country: { "$in": [ObjectId1, ObjectId2, ...] }.